# Sending push notification to specific user in Parse

Tags: parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to create a flow in Cloud Code where I need to send a push notification not to the user that just signed up, but to his partner.

In my app, two Users can be connected as partners. My User table has a `partnerUser` column that points to his partner. So, the flow goes like this:

1) Mark first signs ups in the app and adds his friend's John e-mail address as his partner
1.1) afterSave function is called but does nothing because Mark does not have a partner yet 
2) John receives an email with invite code and signs up using that code. This connects them both in Parse
2.1) afterSave is called based on John's save(). The first thing I do is query the User table to find John's partner - in this case Mark. Then, with Mark's object at hand, I push a notification to Mark.

My logs don't show any error, but the notification is not reaching Mark. Not sure if I am stuffing up with the query itself.

I change the PFInstallation table to have a `Pointer` to the User. And I also have a column in the User table with the InstallationId. With this relationship, I was hoping I could send the individual push notification to a certain user. This is what I do in the cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
    console.log(displayTime() + " - AfterSave Triggered for user " + request.object.get("firstName"));
        //Making sure the partners have been connected
    if (typeof request.object.get("partnerUser") !== 'undefined' || request.object.get("partnerUser") !== null) {

        var topicName = request.object.get("topicName");
        //Searching for the partner (in this case the partner registered first)
        query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        query.equalTo("objectId", request.object.get("partnerUser").id);
        query.doesNotExist("topicName"); //we just want a partner that has not been connected yet
        query.first({
            success: function(userRetrieved) {
                console.log(displayTime() + ' - Partner Retrieved  - name :' + userRetrieved.get("firstName"));
                //We need to send a push notification to the user that first signed up (in this case "userRetrieved")
                //because that user is not connected to the topic that joins both users
                console.log(displayTime() + " - Installation Id is: " + request.object.get("installationId"));
                //var partnerTopicName = request.object.get("partnerUser").id;
                var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
                pushQuery.equalTo('user', userRetrieved);
                pushQuery.equalTo('installationId', request.object.get("installationId"));
                Parse.Push.send({
                    where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
                    data: {
                        "aps": {
                            "content-available": 1,
                            "sound": "default",
                            "title": "Name Me",
                            "alert": "",
                            "type": "connect_push_notification_channel",
                            "topic": topicName
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    useMasterKey: true,
                    success: function() {
                        console.log(displayTime() + " - Push done with installationId " + request.object.get("installationId"));
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        console.error(displayTime() + " - Push error " + err);
                    }
                });
```

Looking at my logs I can see:

[11/10/2016 21:06:32.870 PM] - AfterSave Triggered for user Felipe

```
[11/10/2016 21:06:32.873 PM] - finished for: Felipe
[11/10/2016 21:06:33.24 PM] - Partner Retrieved  - name :Gemma
[11/10/2016 21:06:33.24 PM] - Installation Id is: 2f4b6127-49d5-4586-84eb-595fbb1e3d6a
[11/10/2016 21:06:33.25 PM] - Object UpdateAt equals to Object CreatedAt
[11/10/2016 21:06:33.173 PM] - Push done with installationId 2f4b6127-49d5-4586-84eb-595fbb1e3d6a
[11/10/2016 21:06:33.313 PM] - AfterSave Triggered for user Gemma

[11/10/2016 21:06:33.313 PM] - finished for: Gemma
[11/10/2016 21:06:33.319 PM] - saved
```

I know that push notifications work because I have another flow, from a Cloud Function, that pushes the notification to both users and they both get it. But the query is based on a Topic and not an Installation.

Any tips or advices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what the problem was. It was this line:

```
pushQuery.equalTo('installationId', request.object.get("installationId"));
```

this is actually taking the installationId from the second user, and not the first one, as it should have been. I changed the line to:

```
pushQuery.equalTo('installationId', userRetrieved.get("installationId"));
```

and now it works